# I can't receive the parameters of vue.$http.post ()

Tags: php, vue.js

I had a problem with the vue.$http.post ().It is able to run when the data is delivered to the background,but i just can't receive these params. look this:

```
console.log(data);
vm.$http.post('cybtTypeTapped',data,function(response){
   console.log(response);
   return false;
})
```

I'm trying to deliver an object to the background, and the Network is right.

[image]

Background codes:

```
public function cybtTypeTapped() {
    $input =Input::post();
    var_dump($input);
}
```

**$input** just instance class **Input** and the static function **post()** likes **$_POST['']** , all of them seems correct. But I got an empty object when I put it back to the front.

```
Object {id: "3", type: "2"}  //befor send

<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>  //callback response
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
    <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>

array (size=0)   //Network preview
 empty
```

I'm sorry that i can just send an image. where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your variables via $_POST use FormData() object.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('aa', 'aa value');
data.append('bb', 'bb value');
```